# Laravel 5.2 Many to Many Relationship inverse query empty results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have 2 models `DfpLineItem` and `DfpCreative`

DfpLineItem model with relationship

```
    public function creatives()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\DfpCreative', 'dfp_licas', 'line_item_id', 'creative_id')
        ->withPivot('lica_data')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

As you see this means pivot table is `dfp_licas` which already exists, also there is a timestamps columns and `lica_data` columns.

Everything is fine with this part. When I'm trying to get the data from `DfpLineItem` model, everything is fine and working as expected. For example

`$lineItemData = DfpLineItem::findOrFail($id);` related Creatives exists in this query result and I can access to them like `$lineItemData->creatives`.

Problem appears, when I'm trying to use inverse relationship. Here is my is the relationship defined in my `DfpCreative` model

```
    public function lineItems()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\DfpLineItem', 'dfp_licas', 'creative_id', 'line_item_id')
        ->withPivot('lica_data')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

I think everything is find with this relationship, but when I'm trying to get data like below Id is hardcoded

```
    $orderData = DfpCreative::findOrFail(72174072858);
    dd($orderData->lineItems);
```

Getting empty results, but checked many times, records exists in my `dfp_licas` table.
No Idea why this is happening.

Any help will appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some sleep, with fresh mind found the reason of issue. The hardcoded part `$orderData = DfpCreative::findOrFail(72174072858);` has one simple problem, 72174072858 increases the `PHP_INT_MAX` that my platform supports, xampp 32-bit for my case.

Hopefully this will help someone else in future.